# React: Cannot access index of an array in a state (index undefined)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs

I have an array as a state property in my component, like this:

```
this.state = { postData: [{id: 1, author: 'Mary'}, {id:2, author: 'John'}] }
```

When I access it through **console.log**, such as `this.state.postData[0]`, it shows the contents of the object and works correctly

But when I try to output it as a content of an element, this way:

```
<p>{this.state.postData[0].author}</p>
```

It says that `this.state.postData[0]` is undefined. I so far have not been able to find out why it happens, is there some special way to access arrays in React?

**EDIT: Additional info and context**

Initialization of the state:

```
constructor() {

    super();

    this.state = { postData: '', end : '' };

    this.loadPosts = this.loadPosts.bind(this);

}
```

I am loading data, using AJAX, jQuery, this is the structure of the array that contains post information: (index.js)

```
app.get('/requestPost/12', (req, res) => {
    var jsonPosts = { posts: [ {id:1, author: 'Mary', content: 'Hello, I am Mary'} ] };
    res.send(jsonPosts);
});
```

Then it is received and `postData` state now contains the `posts` array.

```
loadPosts() {

    $.get('/requestPost/12').success( (data) => {

        this.setState({postData : data.posts });

    });

}

componentWillMount() {

    this.loadPosts();

}
```

**Render** function. I noticed an occurence that when I display the `this.state.postData[0]` in console without trying to output it as the elements, it works. However, when I try to use it as an output, as `<p>{this.state.postData[0].author}</p>`, it stops working in the console, too. Also, it does not work when I try to display in the console a property of the postData, like `console.log(this.state.postData[0].author)`

```
render() {

    console.log(this.state.postData[0]);

    return (

    <div>
        <h1>This is the blog we all like</h1>
        <p>{this.state.postData[0].id}</p>
        <p>{this.state.postData[0].author}</p>
        <p>{this.state.postData[0].content}</p>
        <hr/>
    </div>  

    );

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should change initial state., you need set `postData` as empty `Array` with first element as `Object`, because you are trying to get first element from `postData` but gets `undefined`*(`this.state.postData[0]` returns `undefined`)* because it is empty `String` that doesn't/can't have `Object` as a first element

```
this.state = { 
  postData: [{ }], 
  end : '' 
};
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/35366/)

Also you are using `componentWillMount`(triggers before `render`) with AJAX call, but this method does not wait while ajax will be completed. Lifecycle for your application looks like this

1. call `componentWillMount`
2. call `render`
3. ajax was completed
4. set new state
5. call `render` with new state