# Cannot access array of JSON objects as props

Tags: reactjs

I have a React app that consumes a nested JSON object retrieved by an sync AJAX call. On return of the call, I traverse the JSON and bind each of the packets of data the components need to individual state variables.

I then call the components in render - also nested - and pass them the data they and their children need as props.

Passing individual values works well via `<SubComponent dataToUse={this.props.value} />`
However when I pass an array and attempt to .map that array in the component, the browser console gives me the error:

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

...which obviously seems that the array is not actually there - since it is in render, perhaps it is running map before the AJAX call returns the JSON file?
However, if I stringify the array data when binding it to state and pass that, the whole array of data is there, as a string.

If I take *that* string and parse it back into JSON, I get this:

> Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Which again suggests that the data is NOT there.

Suffice it say, I am confused. I can easily pass single data variables down my app hierarchy as props but cannot access arrays.

Has anyone else had this sort of problem?

Edit; some code:

My top most component makes an AJAX call with JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/api/" + eventCode,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        this.setState({updateList: data.updates});
        }.bind(this)
    });
```

This AJAX call sits in its own function and is called every 30 seconds here:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadCommentsFromServer();
    var refreshInterval = 32000; // take this from the blob!
    setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, refreshInterval);  
},
```

The render function is as follows:

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <div id='App'>
            <UpdateList updateData={this.state.updateList}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The UpdateList component is as follows:

```
var UpdateList = React.createClass({

    render: function() {


        return (
            <div id='UpdateList'>
                Update list:
                <ul>
                {
                    this.props.updateData.map(function(update, i){
                        return <Updates singleUpdate={this.props.updateData[i]}/>
                    })
                }
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

If add a simple test array in getInitialState, the array is mapped and the Updates component renders each item just as desired.

Comment: Not really, but if you show some code I might be able to help.

Comment: Added code from Main and UpdateList components

Comment: So what do you get if you console.log `this.state.updateList` in the topmost render method?

Comment: since your request is async, the first time you render that component you wont have an array there. So you do need an initial array there. Is there a problem in doing something like `updateList: []` on the `getInitialState`?

Comment: @hansn logging this.state.updateList in the render method of the main component (where the ajax call is made) happily outputs the entire array that I'm after.

Comment: @AndréJunges I have tried the adding the prop to a state in getInitialState and then calling it in render and it has the same issue; undefined.

Comment: Even the first time? So it outputs the array, and then throws an error right after that?

Comment: I get two, instant undefined's in the console followed by the array in the console from the log in Render of Main. Adding the array as props in UpdateList throws the error and stops the whole app from running

Comment: [Without map function, console.log running in Main app Render component](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yku3l03yjq27rhc/Screenshot%202016-05-18%2020.30.57.png?dl=0)  <--screenshots--> [With map function on array data in UpdateList Render component](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4grkplio09sludr/Screenshot%202016-05-18%2020.33.36.png?dl=0)

Comment: you have done something like this:  
```getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    updateList: []
  }
}```right?

Comment: I have tried the following @AndréJunges : updateList: [] like you suggest in getInitialState of the Main app, then updateData: [] in getInitialState of UpdateList component. Both lead to empty array logged from the final Update component that map calls.

Comment: So NOW, I can run `console.log(this.props.updateData);` in Render of UpdateList and it spits out the array however calling .map on this.props.updateData gives "cannot read property 'props' of undefined"

Comment: I'd suggest you to create a gist or paste it here the full code for both components.. Also if u want a quick fix you can just check if you have an array in that prop before rendering the child

Comment: Okay, thanks @AndréJunges. Feels like I have some progress (I can log the array from Render of UpdateList component). Will have another play and if not, will put up full code later.

Comment: answer found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36114226/react-cannot-access-index-of-an-array-in-a-state-index-undefined)